# Finding characters in the middle of a string that includes "

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following extract of code. My aim is to extract the value **7.4e-07** after the symbol DAN. My usual go-to formula (using MID & FIND formula's) for this can't work because DAN is surrounded by ", and therefore confuses the formula.

`{"data":{"log":{"address":[{"balances":[{"currency":{"address":"example1","symbol":"ROB"},"value":0.0},{"currency":{"address":"example2","symbol":"DAN"},"value":7.4e-07},{"currency":{"address":"example3","symbol":"COLIN"},"value":0.0},{"currency":{"address":"example4","symbol":"BOB"},"value":0.0},{"currency":{"address":"example5","symbol":"PAUL"},"value":13426.64}}}`

I will always need to find the number shown in the 'value' after DAN. However, all other data surrounding will change so cannot be used in the search formula.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Above sample data in one cell or multiple? What would be your exact output from given sample data?

Comment: The sample data copied in the OP is the exact string shown in one cell. The symbol "DAN" would always appear in the data, but the other symbols may change. It is the value shown after DAN that I am needing to extract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extract the digit you want, it can be achieved by using regex, split, index, here is the formula, accept if help :)

```
=index(split(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\""DAN\""},\""value\"":[\d.a-zA-Z-]+"),":"),0,2)
```

[image]

This is the regex I used to extract the value including the beginning text

```
"DAN"},"value":[\d.a-zA-Z-]+
```

This is outcome from the regex,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try an `arrayformula` to work down the sheet, extracting all values after 'DAN':

`=arrayformula(regexreplace(A1:A,".*(DAN...........)([\w\.\-]*)(\}.*)","$2"))`

[image]